# ImpoortXML Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to write an XML formula in Google Sheets that scrapes the text after 'Dividend Yield'

=IMPORTXML("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/intc", XPATH QUERY)

Xpath://*[@id="MainContentContainer"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/section/div[1]/ul/li[13]/span[1]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/intc", 
 "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/section/div[1]/ul/li[13]/span[2]")
```

or shorter:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/intc", 
 "//section/div[1]/ul/li[13]/span[2]")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the complete table of values with xpath =

```
//li[@class='Summary-stat']
```

And then retrieve de Dividend yield for instance by

```
=query(importxml(url,xpath),"select Col2 where Col1='Dividend Yield' ")
```

You can in this way define Dividend Yield as a parameter.
[image]